# Footer "Not the answer you're looking for?" doesn't make much sense

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Currently, the footer below the questions and answers reads

> Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged [...]
>   or ask your own question.

In my opinion the text doesn't work for this site. Is it possible to either remove it or change it into something meaningful?

Comment: related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/477/152

Comment: This is a network wide setting. Unfortunately we can't complete requests for custom changes from single sites.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that footer really adds any value to the site anyway, but if we need to have something there, let's try to keep it positive and encouraging:

> Want to see more puzzles like this? Browse other challenges tagged [...] or pose your own challenge.

(A bigger issue is that the text on the [ask a question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page linked from the footer is completely unsuitable for us, and really should be rewritten too.)

Comment: +1 That's better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab at "something [more] meaningful":

> Not ready to write a program for this challenge? Browse other challenges tagged [...] or pose your own challenge.